# Renderflex object was given an infinite size during layout - flutter error

Tags: flutter, dart, singlechildscrollview

I wanted to make a SingleChileScrollView with extra height. I wrote a code and earlier if was working but now I see a renderflex object error.
It was working one time and suddenly I see this error. Can someone have a look at it and help?

The below is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xdflutter/Component61.dart';
import 'package:xdflutter/Component71.dart';
import 'package:xdflutter/Component81.dart';
import 'package:xdflutter/Component91.dart';
import './Component31.dart';
import './Component22.dart';
import './Component21.dart';
import './start.dart';
import 'package:adobe_xd/page_link.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class Fifth extends StatelessWidget {
  Fifth({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 1000,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 290.0),
              child:
              // Adobe XD layer: 'right' (shape)
              Container(
                width: 315.0,
                height: 287.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/right.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -275.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 434.0,
                child: Text(
                  'What you should know \nbefore you begin? ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 36,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -260.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 348.0,
                height: 108.0,
                child: Component31(),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(-0.5, -376.5),
              child: SvgPicture.string(
                _svg_kr65u6,
                allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -370.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 166.0,
                child: Text(
                  'R:Right',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 15.0),
              child:
              // Adobe XD layer: 'left' (shape)
              Container(
                width: 307.0,
                height: 278.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/left.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -320.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 130.0,
                child: Text(
                  'L:Left',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 50.0),
              child:
              // Adobe XD layer: 'face' (shape)
              Container(
                width: 312.0,
                height: 289.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(54.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/face.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -300.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 142.0,
                child: Text(
                  'F:Face',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 90.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 314.0,
                height: 298.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/back.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -270.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 173.0,
                child: Text(
                  'B: Back ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 130.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 314.0,
                height: 300.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/upper.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -230.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 192.0,
                child: Text(
                  'U: Upper',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 165.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 310.0,
                height: 296.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/down.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -190.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 187.0,
                child: Text(
                  'D: Down',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 145.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 329.0,
                child: Text(
                  'R2: Right twice',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 160.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 312.0,
                height: 294.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/r2.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.5, 170.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 442.0,
                height: 0.0,
                child: Component22(),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 185.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 408.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Counter-clockwise \nrotations',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.5, 380.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 442.0,
                height: 0.0,
                child: Component22(),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 200.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 500.0,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Component61(),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.5, 260.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 442.0,
                height: 0.0,
                child: Component22(),
//        THIS IS IF I NEED TO ADD LINE BELOW SLICE TURNS
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 190.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 238.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Slice turns ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, 280.0),
              child: Container(
                width: 312.0,
                height: 303.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: const AssetImage('assets/images/m_anti.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, -80.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 226.0,
                child: Text(
                  'M: Middle ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 42,
                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 360.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 304.0,
                        height: 297.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: const AssetImage('assets/images/m.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(0.0, -50.0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 338.0,
                                child: Text(
                                  'M\': Middle anti-\nclockwise ',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                                    fontSize: 42,
                                    color: const Color(0xff000000),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(-0.5, 280.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 442.0,
                                height: 0.0,
                                child: Component22(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                                offset: Offset(0.0, 300.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 500,
                                  height: 200,
                                  child: Component71(),
                                ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(5.5, 220.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 305.0,
                                height: 0.0,
                                child: Component22(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(0.0, 235.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 500.0,
                                height: 200.0,
                                child: Component81(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(0.0, 160.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 500.0,
                                height: 200.0,
                                child: Component91(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(5.5, -60.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 305.0,
                                height: 0.0,
                                child: Component22(),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Transform.translate(
                              offset: Offset(0.0, 90.5),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 500.0,
                                height: 0.0,
                                child: Component22(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
//          Transform.translate(
//            offset: Offset(4.0, 250.0),
//            child: PageLink(
//              links: [
//                PageLinkInfo(
//                  transition: LinkTransition.Fade,
//                  ease: Curves.easeOut,
//                  duration: 0.3,
//                  pageBuilder: () => start(),
//                ),
//              ],
//              child: SizedBox(
//                width: 193.0,
//                height: 43.0,
//                child: Text(
//                  'Begin learning! ',
//                  style: TextStyle(
//                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
//                    fontSize: 28,
//                    color: const Color(0xffffffff),
//                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
//                          ),
//                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
//                        ),
//                      ),
//                    ),
//                  ),
                Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 100.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Begin learning!',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 28,
                        color: const Color(0xffffffff)
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(4.0, 100.0),
                child: PageLink(
                  links: [
                    PageLinkInfo(
                      transition: LinkTransition.Fade,
                      ease: Curves.easeOut,
                      duration: 0.3,
                      pageBuilder: () => Fifth(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                      Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(60, 670.5),
                        child: Text(
                          'Start learning!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          ),
                ],
              ),
            ],),
    ),
    ),);
  }
}

const String _svg_kr65u6 =
    '<svg viewBox="-33.5 113.5 442.0 121.0" ><path transform="translate(-33.5, 113.5)" d="M 442 0 L 0 0" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="butt" /><path transform="translate(-33.5, 234.5)" d="M 442 0 L 0 0" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="butt" /></svg>';
```

This is the error I see:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
Restarted application in 2,914ms.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#c6080 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=759.3)
...  size: MISSING
The constraints that applied to the RenderPointerListener were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(392.7, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageLink file:///C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/xdflutter/lib/fourth.dart:516:24
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1967:9)
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2035:6)
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1752:7)
#3      RenderBox.size= (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1754:6)
#4      RenderPointerListener.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2609:5)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPointerListener#99b51 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
...  behavior: translucent
...  listeners: down
RenderObject: RenderPointerListener#99b51 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
  behavior: translucent
  listeners: down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderSemanticsGestureHandler object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageLink file:///C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/xdflutter/lib/fourth.dart:516:24
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#9150f relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
  gestures: tap
  child: RenderPointerListener#99b51 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
    behavior: translucent
    listeners: down
RenderObject: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#9150f relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
  gestures: tap
  child: RenderPointerListener#99b51 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: Size(392.7, Infinity)
    behavior: translucent
    listeners: down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderTransform object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Transform file:///C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/xdflutter/lib/fourth.dart:514:27
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/xdflutter/lib/fourth.dart:24:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1e-10)
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/xdflutter/lib/fourth.dart:24:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: It says the problem is with `fourth.dart`. "The relevant error-causing widget was: lib/fourth.dart:516:24"

Comment: @JigarPatel I know the problem is with the fourth.dart, do you know how I can solve the error?